# nth Fibonacci number divided by 2 to the n

Tags: summation, fibonacci-numbers

Is there any way to calculate
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{F_{2n}}{2^{2n}}$
where $F_n$ is the nth Fibonacci number, $F_1=0$, $F_2=1$, $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$

Comment: Hi, Welcome to MSE.  
AS a hint 
$$f_{2n+1}=f_{2n}+f_{2n-1}$$so we can rewite it as 
$$f_{2n}=f_{2n+1}-f_{2n-1}\to g(n)-g(n-1)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generating function of $F_{2n}$ (as defined here) is
$$\frac{x-x^2}{x^2-3x+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty F_{2n}x^n$$
Substitute $x=\frac14$ to get the sum as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{F_{2n}}{2^{2n}}=\frac{1/4-1/16}{1/16-3/4+1}=\frac35$$

Comment: May be $\frac 45$ if I am not mistaken

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The formulation of Fibonacci numbers in the question is offset by one from the standard formulation. I have noted that.

Comment: I am sorry ! Cheers.

Comment: How did you get the generating function?

Comment: @lisyarus [OEIS A001519](https://oeis.org/A001519) followed by some manipulation in PARI/GP to account for the unusual definition of Fibonacci numbers in the question.